# autosize textarea in angular2

Tags: angular, textarea, autosize

I am working on angular2 applciation. i have a requirement to autosize textarea.
I am trying to reuse the angular2-autosize from https://github.com/stevepapa/angular2-autosize

Followed the readme, But I am getting the below error

Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Vipin\SampleApp\node_modules\angular2-autosize\angular2-autosize.js'.

Please suggest how to overcome this issue.

Comment: If by chance you are using Angular Material, here is a great solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50459162/3310669

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update** (15.04.2018)
Managed to package it, now its available as

```
npm install ngx-autosize
```

https://github.com/chrum/ngx-autosize

**Old answer**:

I had the same problem today and got it fixed! 
Please check my fork:
https://github.com/chrum/angular2-autosize

Until PR is merged try:

```
npm install https://github.com/chrum/angular2-autosize.git --save
```

And then in your code, because it's slightly different, you just import module not directive...

so
**instead of**:

```
import {Autosize} from 'angular2-autosize';

@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [
    Autosize
  ]
  ...
})
```

**you should have**:

```
import {AutosizeModule} from 'angular2-autosize';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    AutosizeModule
  ]
  ...
})
```

Comment: Hi, do you want to support angular5 also ?

Comment: will check its support asap

Comment: ok, i checked it quickly and in all of my projects i had to lock typescript at 2.4.2 to make it work... i guess its time to properly package it and publish on npm so there are no issues like that

Answer (score 37):

The requested behaviour is already implemented in `angular material` as documented here: [Angular Material Input Autosize](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#auto-resizing-code-lt-textarea-gt-code-elements). This is especially useful if you are using `angular material` anyways.

Just use `cdkTextareaAutosize` as in the example:

```
<textarea cdkTextareaAutosize></textarea>
```

Comment: This should be marked as an easier solution! Thanks

Comment: @SnowBases, not really. Not everyone wants all the input lag Material inputs introduce.

Comment: @Patrick i am not that experienced with angular material. may you provide some sources that support that statement. It might be a nice extension to the answer.

Comment: Angular material directive
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/text-field/autosize.ts

Comment: I think this should be the accepted solution.

Comment: strange, added but nothing happens

Answer (score 17):

you can do like this without using the package.
its simple

in controller like below

```
autogrow(){
  let  textArea = document.getElementById("textarea")       
  textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  textArea.style.height = '0px';
  textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

and in html like below

```
<textarea id="textarea" (keyup)="autogrow()" ></textarea>
```

Comment: Although this works, it breaks Angular's philosophy (ie do NOT directly manipulate the DOM). Rather than use document.getElementById, use @ViewChild to get a ref to the textarea (since it is after all a child of the component)

Comment: Good Idea, but the view gets ugly when doing lots of height = 0px then increase, specially in text area with more lines than the entire viewport.

Comment: Resetting the height to 0px is not necessary, and can be done in more smart ways

Comment: And what are those smart ways?

Comment: Yes, we still do not know what the smarter ways are ^^

Answer (score 10):

Why you need plugins for this, it's as simple as :

```
<textarea (keyup)="autoGrowTextZone($event)"></textarea>
```

and

```
autoGrowTextZone(e) {
  e.target.style.height = "0px";
  e.target.style.height = (e.target.scrollHeight + 25)+"px";
}
```

Comment: How to do for the detailed page ?

Answer (score 7):

Slightly modified answer for tanveer's answer would be to use @ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('textArea', { read: ElementRef }) textArea: ElementRef;

public autoGrow() {
 const textArea = this.textArea.nativeElement;
 textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
 textArea.style.height = '0px';
 textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

And in the HTML it would be

```
<textarea (keyup)="autoGrow()" #textArea></textare>
```

Comment: As MohammadKermani commented on Tanveer's answer, "Resetting the height to 0px is not necessary, and can be done in more smart ways"

Comment: If you have more then one textarea elements:

      @ViewChild('textArea1', { read: ElementRef }) textArea1: ElementRef;
      @ViewChild('textArea2', { read: ElementRef }) textArea2: ElementRef;

    public autoGrow(name) {
      const textArea = this[name].nativeElement;
      textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      textArea.style.height = '0px';
      textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight - 20 + 'px';
    }

Answer (score 6):

The solution that worked for me on IE as well as in the other browser

```
// Usage example: <textarea autoresize></textarea>

import { ElementRef, HostListener, Directive} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: 'textarea[autosize]'
})

export class Autosize {
 @HostListener('input',['$event.target'])
  onInput(textArea: HTMLTextAreaElement): void {
    this.adjust();
  }
  constructor(public element: ElementRef){
  }
  ngAfterContentChecked(): void{
    this.adjust();
  }
  adjust(): void{
    this.element.nativeElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    this.element.nativeElement.style.height = 'auto';
    this.element.nativeElement.style.height = this.element.nativeElement.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
}
```

Add the below code to the APp.Module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Autosize
  ]
})
```

Use the tag on the HTML

```
 <textarea autosize></textarea>
```

Answer (score 5):

## Simply

You can use as below:

```
<textarea [rows]="text.split('\n').length || 2">{{text}}</textarea>
```

## or

create a function in ts :

```
  getHeight(content) {
    const v1 = Math.floor(content.length / 50);
    const v2 = content.split('\n').length;
    return Math.max(v1,v2)
  }
```

HTML:

```
<textarea [rows]="getHeight(text) || 2">{{text}}</textarea>
```

Comment: Simply brilliant!

Answer (score 3):

Create the directive from angular-cli and add following code

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
selector: '[appAutoGrow]'
})
export class AutoGrowDirective {

constructor(public element: ElementRef) {
}
@Input() maximumHeight: number; // based on pixel
@Input() minHeight: number; // based on pixel
@HostListener('input', ['$event.target'])
@HostListener('cut', ['$event.target'])
@HostListener('paste', ['$event.target'])
@HostListener('change', ['$event.target'])

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.adjustCustom();
}

adjustCustom(): void {
    const element = this.element.nativeElement;
    element.style.height = this.minHeight + 'px';
    element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight) + 'px';
    if (element.scrollHeight <= this.maximumHeight) {

        element.style.overflowY = 'hidden'
        delete element.style.maxHeight
    } else {

        element.style.overflowY = 'scroll'
        element.style.maxHeight = this.maximumHeight + 'px';
    }

}
}
```

and use the directive as follows

```
<textarea autofocus [maximumHeight]="200" [minHeight]="43" appAutoGrow></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the topic is quite old but I just change tanveer's answer to enter maximum Height as well.

```
    import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutoResize]',

})
export class AutoResizeDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(public element: ElementRef) {
  }
  @Input() maximumHeight: number; // based on pixel
  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target'])
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.adjust();
  }

  adjust(): void {
    const ta = this.element.nativeElement;
    const maxHeghit = this.maximumHeight;
    ta.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    ta.style.height = 'auto';
    if (ta.scrollHeight <= maxHeghit) { // while current height is less than maximumHeight
      ta.style.height = ta.scrollHeight + 'px';
    } else { // greater than maximumHeight
      ta.style.height = maxHeghit + 'px';
      ta.style.overflow = 'auto';
    }
  }

}
```

So, you will have control on the style behavior.
I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation of `autosize` in a directive which you can reuse on any textarea in your project.

```
import { Directive, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: 'textarea[autosize]'
})

export class TextareaAutosizeDirective {

    private _ngModel: any;

    public get ngModel(): any {
        return this._ngModel;
    }

    @Input()
    public set ngModel(value: any) {
        if (this._ngModel !== value) {
            this._ngModel = value;
            this.resize();
        }
    }

    @HostBinding('rows')
    public rows: number;

    @Input()
    public minRows: number = 1;

    constructor() {}

    private resize() {
        this.rows = !this._ngModel ? this.minRows : this.ngModel.split('\n').length;
    }

}
```

You can use it in a following way:

```
<textarea autosize minRows="2" [(ngModel)]="property"></textarea>
```

By adding `autosize` textarea becomes automatically resized. You can also specify minimum number of rows which textarea has.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late but let me provide my answer as well.
Just simply follow the following

```js
  adjustTextareaHeight() {
    const textarea: HTMLTextAreaElement = document.querySelector('textarea');
    textarea.style.height = 'auto';
    textarea.style.height = `${textarea.scrollHeight}px`;
  }
```

```html
<textarea (input)="adjustTextareaHeight()"></textarea>
```