# Change size of textarea

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I currently have a `textarea` like this:

```
<textarea matInput rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="text"></textarea>
```

However, it is always the same size.

Any idea on how to change the size of the `textarea`?

Comment: Could you accept my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47402588/3345644) or let me know how I could improve it, please?

Answer (score 122):

Depending on what you've meant by:

> However, it is always the same size.

There are two options.

### OPTION 1 (STATIC size depending on `rows` \ `cols`):

Currently, only `rows` affects the Material `textarea` height, `cols` doesn't change its width.

Therefore for increasing width, we have to use the CSS `width` property on a `mat-form-field` containing our `textarea`:

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 300px;">
    <textarea matInput rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="text"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

### OPTION 2 (DYNAMIC size to fit `textarea` content):

In Material 6, `CdkTextareaAutosize` directive was added.

From an [official docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/text-field/overview):

> The cdkTextareaAutosize directive can be applied to any `<textarea>` to
>   make it automatically resize to fit its content. The minimum and
>   maximum number of rows to expand to can be set via the
>   `cdkAutosizeMinRows` and `cdkAutosizeMaxRows` properties respectively.

And here's a simplified example from there:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Autosize textarea</mat-label>
    <textarea
        matInput
        cdkTextareaAutosize
        cdkAutosizeMinRows="1"
        cdkAutosizeMaxRows="5">
    </textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

**NOTE:**
`matTextareaAutosize` mentioned in other answers is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. The [official docs](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview) already use `cdkTextareaAutosize` instead.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Why hasn't this been accepted?

Comment: for me, this solution saved my day...

Answer (score 36):

Here's an example :

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
  <textarea matInput formControlName="description" matTextareaAutosize matAutosizeMinRows=1 matAutosizeMaxRows=5></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Reference: https://material.angular.io/components/input/api

Answer (score 13):

Angular materials 7.2:
https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Autosize textarea</mat-label>
  <textarea matInput cdkTextareaAutosize
            cdkAutosizeMinRows="2"
            cdkAutosizeMaxRows="5"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Pay attention to `cdkTextareaAutosize`, `cdkAutosizeMinRows`, `cdkAutosizeMaxRows`

Answer (score 3):

See [example](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview). It is important to add css to the form to specify the width:

```
.example-form {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

and also css to the textarea:

```
.example-full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

If you do not add the css to the form, then the expand icon displays in the incorrect position.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to adjust the hight of your texarea by applying `matTextareaAutosize` and assigning values for properties `matAutosizeMinRows` and `matAutosizeMaxRows`.

See https://material.angular.io/components/input/api for additional details.